# Dropzone with some other parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I upload image using Dropzone. I need to send some other values via that(Some text values).In my scenario i need to send Product Name to the controller(pls see some comment in code)

Image successfully comes to the Controller's side,when button click.

**HTML Code :**

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="txtprod" class="form-control" />

<div id="dropzonffe" style="width: 55%; margin-left: 25%">
    <form action="~/Admin/SaveProducts" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneJsForm"></form>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {

    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
        var myDropzone = this;

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var ProductName = $("#txtprod").val();//<-- I want to send this Productname to the controller also.
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

**My Controller :**

```
public ActionResult SaveProducts () {
    bool isSavedSuccessfully = false;

    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files) {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
        isSavedSuccessfully = true;
    }
    return Json (new { isSavedSuccessfully, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
}
```

I need to pass the Product Name to the controller. How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the formcollection? 
public ActionResult SaveProducts(FormCollection fc) {... }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.Here i have paste it for future help.There's a event in DropZone called `sending`.you can pass additional parameters via append to form data.

```
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneJsForm = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
        var myDropzone = this;

        this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("ProductName", $("#txtprod").val());


        });

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        myDropzone.processQueue();

        });

    }
};
```

Access it in Server Side

```
 public ActionResult SaveProducts(string ProductName)
    {

     }
```

Comment: how ablout multiple upload. It will have many ProductName parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model

```
public class ProductModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Add inside the form the `Name`

```
<div id="dropzonffe" style="width: 55%; margin-left: 25%">
    <form action="~/Admin/SaveProducts" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneJsForm">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name);
    </form>
</div>
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

And pass in Action the `Model`, the value from inputs will be sent alongside with files.

```
public ActionResult SaveProducts(ProductModel product)
{
     // rest of the logic
```

Comment: But in here you use Html helper control ( @Html ) know ? i use <input> textbox.How can i do that .. pls see updated OP

Comment: @Alex in your case will be  `<input type="text" name="ProductName" id="txtprod" class="form-control" />`

Comment: I struggled to get this work for ages until I finally got the configuration right. I'm not sure what exactly I was doing wrong but now it works a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Add the values as a hidden field to your form and they will be sent to your controller

```
<form action="~/Admin/SaveProducts" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneJsForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="SomeVal" />
```

and then

```
public ActionResult SaveProducts(string SomeVal) 
{

   ..controller body
}
```

or the FormCollection object would work as well

```
public ActionResult SaveProducts(FormCollection fc) 
{
     //use fc["SomeVal"]
   ..controller body
}
```