# How can I upload form elements along with limited number of files in php using dropzone 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone

Please can any one assist, I want to upload my form input elements with 4 images and only images to be picked on file browse and showed on my file preview template **div** in php using codeigniter framework I do see my previews but on submit I get error " Undefined index: file " have searched for the solution for 5days now: Here are my Codes:

**View**

```
<head>

    <link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/libs/dropzone/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App css -->
    <link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="bs-default-stylesheet" />
    
</head>

<body class="loading">

                    <form action="<?=base_url();?>AdminController/do_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="card-box">
                                <h5 class="text-uppercase bg-light p-2 mt-0 mb-3">General</h5>
                                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                    <label for="product-category">Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2" name="category" >
                                        <option>Select</option>
                                        <optgroup label="Animal Category">
                                            <?php $animalCategories=$this->Main_Model->fetch_all("livestock_categories");
                                                foreach($animalCategories As $category):?>
                                                <option value="<?=$category->id?>"><?=$category->name;?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach?>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end card-box -->
                        </div> <!-- end col -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="card-box">
                                <h5 class="text-uppercase mt-0 mb-3 bg-light p-2">Product Images</h5>
                                <div action="<?=base_url();?>AdminController/do_upload" id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone"  data-plugin="dropzone" data-previews-container="#file-previews"
                                    data-upload-preview-template="#uploadPreviewTemplate">
                                    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                                        <i class="h1 text-muted dripicons-cloud-upload"></i>
                                        <h3>Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Preview -->
                                <div class="dropzone-previews mt-3" id="file-previews"></div>

                            </div> <!-- end col-->
                            <div class="card-box">
                                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <br/><button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn w-sm btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            </div> <!-- end card-box -->
                        </div> <!-- end col-->
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- end row -->

                    <!-- file preview template -->
                    <div class="d-none" id="uploadPreviewTemplate">
                        <div class="card mt-1 mb-0 shadow-none border">
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <div class="row align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                      <img data-dz-thumbnail src="#" class="avatar-sm rounded bg-light" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col pl-0">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="text-muted font-weight-bold" data-dz-name></a>
                                        <p class="mb-0" data-dz-size></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <!-- Button -->
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-link btn-lg text-muted" data-dz-remove>
                                            <i class="dripicons-cross"></i>
                                        </a>
    <!-- END wrapper -->
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Dropzone file uploads-->
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/libs/dropzone/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone={
            autoProcessQueue: FALSE,
            maxFilesize:4,
            acceptedFiles: '.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif',
            init:function(){
                var submitButton=document.querySelector('#submit-all');
                myDropzone=this;
                submitButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
                this.on("complete",function(){}); 
                if(this.getQueueFiles().length==0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length==0){
                    _this.removeAllFiles();
                }

            },
        }


    </script>
    
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function do_upload(){

       $dataInfo = array();
       $cpt = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
       $files = $_FILES;
       for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){           
           $_FILES['file']['name']= $files['file']['name'][$i];
           $_FILES['file']['type']= $files['file']['type'][$i];
           $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']= $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
           $_FILES['file']['error']= $files['file']['error'][$i];
           $_FILES['file']['size']= $files['file']['size'][$i];    

           $this->load->library('upload');
           $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
           $this->upload->do_upload('file');
           $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
       }

       $data = array(
           'prod_image' => $dataInfo[0]['file_name'],
           'prod_image1' => $dataInfo[1]['file_name'],
           'prod_image2' => $dataInfo[2]['file_name'],
           'prod_image3' => $dataInfo[3]['file_name']
        );
       print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: I think you should have a different action for the form because do_upload is used by Dropzone for uploading the images when it processes the queue, one file at a time. But when your form submits there are no files in the submitted data. I think you may run into a problem though because the page could submit before all the images have finished being uploaded. It might be better to prevent submit of the form and pass additional data with each file, does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547244/dropzone-with-some-other-parameters/29547593

Comment: @Mark Even after changing to that no file is atleast uploaded